# elasticsearch aggregation with date comparision and calcul

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-aggregation

Hi i am kinda new to elasticsearch. I need to get an aggregation with date comparison and a dynamic range filter.

Like i need to get documents count where created_at document is 1 week earlier than their identification_date.

So i tried something like this but my date param seems unused, actually changing it never changes my results.

```
       "aggs": {
            "identified": {
                "terms": { 
                    "script": "doc['created_at'].value > (doc['identification_date'].value - diff_date) 
                               && doc['created_at'].value < doc['identification_date'].value",
                    "params": {
                        "diff_date": 604800
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thank you for taking time helping.

Comment: For those who come later i found out that the elasticsearch calculs on dates are supposed to be in microseconds, so i just needed to have a diff_date of 604800000

Answer (score 0):

since on the abstracted level you just want count of documents created 7 days before on some date field.you don't need aggregation for this if you don't want to group the results sets further on some fields.Simply you can a)use range filter query on your date field

```
{
    "range" : {
        "date" : {
            "gte" : "now-7d/d",
            "lt" :  "now"
        }
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: Actually not because it s a part of a bigger query. And range aggregations doesn't show comparaison with the identification_date which is the main info here. but thank you for your suggestion anyway :)

Comment: then you can use filter range/aggs and term aggregation together in aggregations.Filter aggs will be a range filter and term aggregator will aggregate your documents on date fields.

Comment: or if better approach is what you want use date_histogram aggregation on your date field and define buckets on date range.